# Box-Jenkins to prove model

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, box-jenkins

Suppose the $X_t$ satisfies:

$$\phi_1 (B) X_t = \theta_1 (B) Z_t, \tag{$*$}$$

where $\{Z_t\},$ $WN(0, \sigma_Z^2)$ and $\phi_1 (\cdot)$ and $\theta_1 (\cdot)$ are polynomials of order $p_1$ and $q_1$, respectively.

Suppose we calculate the residuals from fitting the model in $(*)$. Let's suppose that the residuals are the $\{Z_t\}$'s. Based upon the ACF and PACF from the residuals $\{Z_t\}$, suppose that you decide that the residuals are an $\operatorname{ARMA}(p_2,q_2)$ model:

$$\phi_2 (B) Z_t = \theta_2 (B) W_t, \tag{$**$}$$ where $\{W_t\}$, $WN(0,\sigma_w^2)$,
so we can write this as: $Z_t = \left[\frac{\theta_2 (B)}{\phi_2 (B)}\right] W_t$.

Using $(*)$ and $(**)$, show that we obtain a model of the form:
$$\varphi (B)X_t = \theta (B)W_t, \tag{$***$}$$ where $\{W_t\}$, $WN(0,\sigma_w^2)$.

So, I think the way I'm supposed to approach this problem is by finding the orders ($p_3$ and $q_3$) of $\varphi$ and $\theta$. I feel like the answer is implicit, because this is simply how Box-Jenkins works. I'm not sure what work can be done to show that this is what occurs.